# Conditional format not completely consistent for currency in MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 textboxes on a form that I match to make sure currency values are exactly the same.  However, sometimes even though they visually match, the conditional format interprets that they are different.  I was certain that it had something to do with rounding or field format, so I tried making sure that both fields are currency and 3 decimal places, but I still get seemingly sporadic results. Most of the time when they visually match, the conditional format of showing a box as 'green' is working.  But it is very disturbing when the box turns red when clearly the values in both boxes are visually the same. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a delta. Initialize a tiny value, take the difference of your two currency values, and compare that difference against the delta. If the difference is less than your delta value, the currencies are 'equal.'

```
delta = .0001
diff = absolute value (currency1 - currency2)
if diff < delta then currency1 = currency2
```